# Does the boarding port need to be in the country of visa issue?

Tags: visas, china

I currently have a visa to travel to China that was issued in Switzerland. But I've realized that I may be better off starting (and ending) my journey in the UK.

Is this something that is allowed, or is there a need to travel from the country of visa issue?

Note that this question has already been asked regarding a [Schengen visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38603/does-my-boarding-port-to-the-schengen-area-need-to-be-in-the-country-in-which-i). But since my question is for a China visa, I thought that it isn't an exact duplicate.

Comment: While China _could_, in principle, be different, the answers to the questions you link explain that countries are very unlikely to care about this, both because people want to make multi-country trips and because having to make a connection in a third country is extremely common -- there might not even _be_ any direct flights.

Comment: Anecdotally I can tell you I got my Chinese visa at the consulate in Chicago and entered by train from Mongolia. If I remember correctly the immigration form asks where your visa was issued, but other than that they don't care.

Answer (score 5):

In general **no country cares where you start your journey from.**

Exceptions to this principle are very rare - for example if you were claiming to be escaping from the oppressive regime of country X but were transiting through country X.

Comment: For one thing, it's routine to change planes and even if you originated in Switzerland, your immediate entry could be a flight from the UK (Germany, etc.).